# No connection popup in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I have a "network check" that runs when you click on the `Check Connection` button and I need it to run when the app loads. I have had a go with popping it in a function with no sucess. Can anyone spot the function syntax error in my `if states == ...`?

**Check connection by clicking `Check Connection`**

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {NavController, Platform, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

    declare var navigator: any;
    declare var Connection: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController) { }

        checkNetwork() {
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
                var states = {};
                states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
                states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                // this. was missing
                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: "Connection Status",
                    subTitle: states[networkState],
                    buttons: ["OK"]
                });

                // This is the proper way to present the alert
                alert.present();
            });
        }

    }
```

**Display Prompt If No Connection**

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {NavController, Platform, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

    declare var navigator: any;
    declare var Connection: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController) { }

       ionViewDidLoad() {
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
                var states = {};
                states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                if (states == states[Connection.NONE]) {

                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: "Connection Status",
                    subTitle: states[networkState],
                    buttons: ["OK"]
                });

                alert.present();

                }

            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: the condition should be ` if (networkState == Connection.NONE)`

Comment: Tried that but no prompt when installed on mobile with internet switched off. hard to daignose in browser console as it is running network info - just reads "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

Comment: you could try http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigator.connection` is still in an experimental phase. It is not supported on the desktop so you are not going to get anything useful in testing on your browser. You have not mentioned if you are testing on your browser or through to your device, but maybe something to keep in mind. Your code might be fine.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection

`navigator.connection.type` will return one the following

```
bluetooth
cellular
ethernet
none
wifi
wimax
other
mixed
```

If you set your conditional to test again `none`, i don't see why it will not work.

```
...
   navigator.connection.type === 'none' ? this.isOffline() : console.log('online');
}

isOffline(){
   return this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Connection Status',
              subTitle: 'No network connection',
              buttons: ["OK"]
           }).present();
 }
```